# Sending message to facebook page using python Flask

Tags: python, facebook, api, flask

I want to send a message to a facebook page using my flask app but i keep getting a 400 bad request error please where am I doing it wrong or is there a better way to do this. This is the code

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
  print("Request:")
  print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

  res = processRequest(req)
  print(res)

  url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages'
  payload = res
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  print(r)
  return r

def processRequest(req):
  request = req.get("originalRequest")
  first_data = request.get("data")
  sender = first_data.get("sender")
  user_id = sender.get("id")
  speech = "hello"

  print("Response:")
  print(speech)
  token ="my_access_token"

  return {
    "recipient": {
        "id": user_id
    },
    "message": speech,
    'access_token': token
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
  port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

  print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

  app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Please any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Go check the body of the API response, it should contain an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass a valid "access_token" in the request? If not, the server side will return a 400 bad request error. With the correct "access_token" value, a request looks like below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "USER_ID"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Please read the official Facebook API Reference from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#request) for more details.

Comment: I am using the correct access_token  value from the facebook page but I am not using using curl.

Comment: thanks for the response I think am going to try a few more things